# jQuery: going through all visible rows of a table

Tags: jquery, visibility, tablerow

I need to write some code that would loop though all rows of a table, then check a hidden input in each row to see if it contains a certain value and if so, set some values and hide the row.
It might be clumsy, but it worked:
(variable "zeile" contains the first row, is initialized correctly before the loop):

```
while (goon) {
  var hf = zeile.attr('id');
  if (hf) {
      hf = document.getElementById(hf.substr(0,hf.length-2) + 'hfMat');
      if (hf.value == mid) {
          found=true;
          goon=false;
          zeile.hide();
     } else {
         cnt +=1 ;
         if (cnt<10) {
               alert('not found, cnt=' + cnt);
            } else {
               goon=false;
         }
       }
     }

     if (goon) {
        zeile = zeile.next('tr');
        goon=zeile.length>0;
     }
}
```

Ok, first of all, line 4 with the `document.getElementById(hf...)` looks like admitting defeat and it probably is - but `$("#"+hf).val()` just wouldn't do it, returned undefined :(

As I said, this code works fine. BUT then I had a case where two rows contained the same value in the hfMat-field, and my script would then hide the first row again, whereas it should have continued to the second. "Easy", I thought, and improved the statement to determine the next row to process (4th line from the end), so I changed from `zeile = zeile.next('tr');` to `zeile = zeile.next('tr:visible');`
However, with jQuery 1.3.2, this doesn't work and I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

And surely, there must be a much better way to get this selection done without such messy looping, by simply using some of jQuery's more advanced mechanisms, but I'm afraid these are beyond me atm. But I'd be happy to see some ideas ;)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include a sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply hide an element, it is not taken out of the document flow. Therefore, it will continue to get located by your DOM queries.

Without seeing your actual HTML, I can only speculate that what you're trying to accomplish can be done in a simpler way with the following jQuery loop:

```
$("tr input[value=" + mid + "]").each(function () {
    this.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ates, that sample makes a strong case  for the power of jQuery's selection machanisms.

Yet, your remark about hiding and element still getting located does not totaly hit the nail on the head, that was and is understood, but the question is why then does the zeile = zeile.next('tr:visible'); not match the next visible line.

And sorry for not providing a sample here, the current code contains tons of controls not relevant for this problem. I'll try to make a boiled-down version of that sample...